# Django filter between two date

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My django model datetime field is string. In this case, how to get data between two dates?

*models.py*

```
class asdf(models.Model):
     recordDate = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
```

Comment: Why do you use a `CharField` in the first place? This will result in a lot of problems (especially if time zones are involved, or the format is not YYYYMMDD, or something that goes in increasing granularity).

Comment: so, at first times this is easy, but for query this is useless, if I haven't any choice I will change this field type

Comment: well it will only result in more trouble. By using a `DateField`, first of all the database will protect you against invalid input (for example now you can, by mistake, enter `recordDate = 'blablabla'). If it is a `DateField`, the database will reject that. But it is typically more compact to use a `DateField` as well, and databases are optimized to filter, etc. on dates. Actually there are not much reasons to store datetimes as text.

Answer (score 21):

Change the 'recordDate' to DateField and use the following query:

```
asdf.objects.filter(recordDate__gte='2019-03-01', recordDate__lte='2019-03-09')
```

Answer (score 7):

In order to get between range use filter this query:

```py
models.asdf.objects.filter(recordDate__gte='start_date', recordDate__lt='end_date')
```

`start_date` and `end_date` may be string in date formats or datetime parsed object.

Comment: this will not work, you can use django.db.models.Q with | or operator for this purpose.

Comment: btw, you wrote start and end the other way.

Answer (score 5):

This is working for me
*remember one thing what you are storing in you db means only date or datetime*

**when datetime**

```
start = '2021-08-12 21:52:33.118649'
end = '2021-08-13 06:30:46.909572'
user = UserAccount.objects.filter(created_at__gte=start, 
created_at__lte=end)
print user
```

**when date**

```
start = '2021-08-12'
end = '2021-08-13'
user = UserAccount.objects.filter(created_at__gte=start, 
created_at__lte=end)
print user
```

**or you can filter by using __range here also**

```
start = '2021-08-12 21:52:33.118649'
end = '2021-08-13 06:30:46.909572'
user = UserAccount.objects.filter(created_at__range=(start, end))
print user
```

**if you you are storing in db datatime and you want to retrieve only date from db**

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('2014-12-04', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```